# Rewrite rules for a branch of content formerly under a CNAME alias

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, data-migration, cname, redirect

I'm migrating a blog installation to a new server. The original installation was on an Amazon server. The new server location will be the true server that the Amazon install was made to appear at through some DNS changes and a Cname alias.

The aliased URLs looked like this...

**blog.domain.tld/articles/{title of articles}**

At the new and true domain location, the false "blog" aliasing will be dropped, and the new URL structure will be...

**domain.tld/articles/{title of articles}**

I need to setup some mod_rewrite rules so that calls to the old fake URLs will land people at the new and true ones. I've seen good examples online of root-to-subdirectory or subdirectory-to-root redirects on the same server, but in this case where the faux subdirectory was involved on a different server, I'm not sure what to do. I'm not even sure it makes sense (or is possible) to redirect from an aliased URL.

Anyone have any pointers, insights, or examples? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to just redirecting www. links to non-www links, so the following should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.tld$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So obvious, about the "www." part. Yet I would have never put that together. Thanks Steve, I'll give it a try and follow-up after.

Comment: Those rules worked great, Steve. Thanks a a lot. (Now to get some DNS zone file issues cleared up.)